# Akeeba Backup component copy failed error joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am not able to install akeeba backup 3.9.2 version component in joomla 2.5.11 .I have tried it by increasing the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`.And also given directory permissions to the the folders needed. But it still its giving errors **"Copy failed -1"**.Please let me know some solutions to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try/check:

- is there sufficient free space in your web hosting account?
- check the permissions on the tmp folder
- check the upload_max_filesize in <kbd>Site -> System Information -> PHP
  Information</kbd> is sufficient for the installation file to be uploaded
- try installing a different extension to check if it is issue with the
  Akeeba install specifically rather than a permission or file size
  issue
- try updating to the latest version of Joomla
- try installing the latest version of Akeeba Backup (3.10.0 as I write
  this)
- check the PHP file handler at <kbd>Site -> System Information ->
  System Information -> WebServer to PHP Interface</kbd> - there could
  be a file ownership issue if this is set to the default apache file handler
  rather than suPHP or FCGI etc and you may need to escalate this issue to your hosting provider

You should probably update Joomla to the latest version in any case to keep it secure.